# Why has the apache2 www dir been moved to /var/www/html?

Tags: apache, apache2

I just upgraded my server and saw that the `default.conf` file in sites-available was now pointing to `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www`. What was the reason for this change?

Comment: I think u mean the httpd.conf ?

Comment: What did you upgrade from? What did you upgrade to?

Check the bug tracker of whoevers package you're using.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the bug report: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372

The report was filed after this mailing list discussion: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2012/04/msg00301.html

**Summary:** Site admins usually place sites in `/var/www/site.com` and there may be sensitive data in `/var/www` that should not be made available via a web server. All web servers on Debian have been updated to use `/var/www/html` as default instead of `/var/www`.

Comment: Love it, no need to read a novel, it is straight to the point, instructive, and explains very well why html is the new default path! Thanks @f.ardelian

Answer (score 28):

I edited /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to fix this (changed the DocumentRoot line).

The reason given for this breaking change is nonsense. Why would a site administrator put sensitive files that aren't supposed to be served to the web in /var/www , of all places? I'm just a developer and I know what that directory does.

If an administrator is lazy or incompetent enough to put sensitive files in /var/www, nothing will stop them from putting those files in /var/www/html now. And since when does Linux break backward compatibility in a useless attempt to prevent administrators from doing really dumb things?

Comment: Because it's common for developers to use a path like /var/www/<something> and to put config files one level above that so they are out of the webroot.  A developer following that pattern may not realise that in this environment there's a gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

I went with the don't fight the power philosophy and just moved all my files from the /var/www to the /var/www/html folder. It all worked fine including the mySQL services. Also keep in mind web hosting services will probably force you to use the html directory.